# How to handle errors in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have #NAME? -error on a cell, which produces runtime error 13 when i execute the code below. The error handler is not working, please tell me why? I cant solve this.

```
Sub loop()
Dim RangeCell As Range
x = 2

On Error GoTo Errorhandler

For Each RangeCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A9050:A9055")

    If InStr(1, RangeCell, "99999") Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 1) = RangeCell.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 2) = RangeCell.Offset(-1, 0)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 3) = RangeCell.Offset(-2, 0)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 4) = RangeCell.Offset(-3, 0)
        If InStr(1, RangeCell.Offset(-4, 0), "Cat no:") Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 5) = RangeCell.Offset(-4, 0)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 6) = RangeCell.Offset(-5, 0)
            Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 6) = RangeCell.Offset(-4, 0)
            End If
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 7) = RangeCell.Row
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 8) = RangeCell.Offset(0, 28)
 x = x + 1
    End If
    
Errorhandler:
Debug.Print RangeCell.Address


Next RangeCell
End Sub
```

Comment: `IsError(RangeCell)`

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Comment: Sub loop() is highlighted as an illegal statement on my PC so I would question if you have ever run this code.

Comment: Define "not working". Does it not catch the error at all, i.e. not jumping to the `Errorhandler` label? Or does it keep raising the error? Also: the error handler should be placed outside any control block.